# Why is my Style.trigger event not working for my WPF Datagrid?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, wpf-controls

I have a DataGrid in WPF and created a ControlTemplate for it at the setters. Before I created this ControlTemplate, my Style.trigger worked with the IsMouseOver event perfectly. But after placing the Controltemplate its not working anymore. This is my code:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#292F3B"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightBlue"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,2,0" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#333333"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 0 0 0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                <Border Background="#242A36">
                                    <Border BorderThickness="1"
                                        CornerRadius="6"
                                        Background="#2D2D30"
                                        Padding="10,0,0,0"
                                        Margin="2">
                                        <ContentPresenter/>
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>


                </Style>
```

So I only want that the IsMouseOver effect is working with the ControlTemplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `<Style.Triggers>` to now be inside the ControlTemplate as a `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>` and you should see it changing the background again.  But you'll have to identify the target for the background using the `Target` attribute, because WPF won't be smart enough to know which background you are talking about.

**Here's an example:**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="mystyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#292F3B"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightBlue"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,2,0" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#333333"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 0 0 0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" Background="#242A36">
                        <Border BorderThickness="1"
                                    CornerRadius="6"
                                    Background="#2D2D30"
                                    Padding="10,0,0,0"
                                    Margin="2">
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid CanUserAddRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Stuff}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn HeaderStyle="{StaticResource mystyle}" Header="Name"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

**Here's what this would look like if you hover the mouse over the header.**

Note: I didn't know exactly what you wanted to change colors, so I just picked the outside border that you defined

[image]

Comment: Glad to hear it, Doc. :D